# What is the main difference between gates and middlewares in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-middleware, laravel-gate

people,
I just want to ask a very clear question. i know that is the middleware is used to authenticate a user but the gate and policy come to restrict user behavior depending his/her role. I used LARAVEL gates to redirect the user to the login page if he is not authenticated So, the question is: Does LARAVEL middleware contains Gates in it or what ??
Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

**Gates**

Gates are basically used to check that a user is authorized to perform a given action.

**Middleware**

Middleware provide a way for inspecting and filtering HTTP requests which are entering in your application. For example: Laravel includes a middleware that verifies that the user of your application is authenticated. and you can define your own middleware.